# Navbar alignment with click?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble to align my image to the navbar correctly its slightly to the side. I am trying to set it out so that it fits with the navbar together in the white area.
So when you click on the image the navbar pops up below it.

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.menu-bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    height: 14px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

.logo {

    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;


}
.menu {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 10px 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.menu ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.menu a {
    color: #333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.menu a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 1;
}
/*deviders*/
.home{
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #423840;
}

.about {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #8dd8f8;
}

.service {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #9D714F;
}

.info{
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #eee;
}

.contact {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<head>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</head>
  <body class="scroll-area" data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0">
    <a class="menu-bar" data-toggle="collapse" href="#menu">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Bu0B6O8.png" alt="Logo" class = "logo">
            </a>
         <div class="collapse menu" id="menu">

                <ul class="list-inline">

                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#service">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#info">Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
         </div>



<section id="home" class="home">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <h1>Home</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="about" class="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Profolio</h1>
                <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="service" class="service">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Service</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Contact Section -->
<section id="info" class="info">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Info</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<section id="contact" class="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Contact us</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: use the bootstrap class .img-responsive to your image.set margin-top:whatever you want.

Comment: @user3386779 its still not aligned with the navbar.

Comment: you want to stick the logo in white color div rite?

Comment: @user3386779 yes but when you click on it menu pops up and its not alighted with the menu in the middle.

Comment: then where you want to align?

Comment: with the text   <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#service">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#info">Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make little change in your css, Just replace the below css code. I hope it work for you.

---

```
.menu-bar {
top: 20px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: table;}
```

Comment: Yeah it works good but now there is to much white space on top.

Comment: Remove padding-top in body tag, Or adjust as your requirement.